# How do I fix/cover this hole in my kitchen subfloor?

Tags: flooring, kitchens

Can anyone advise on how to fix a hole in my kitchen floor? I just bought a house in the UK, and the previous owners removed their Aga cooker. The Aga evidently needed a supply of something through the floor - in any case there is a hole in the floor just where the leg of the new range cooker will sit.

I need to have a solid weight bearing surface where the hole is. The material is 7/8 inch thick. There are joists to to either side a few inches away.

Can I safely cut the existing flooring away to expose the joists, and then drop in a new piece? Would I fasten them to the joists with screws or nails?

Note - this will be hidden under the cooker, so no worries about appearance.

[image]

Comment: sound like a plan, BUT what was the hole for ?

Comment: What is the flooring material made of? Greg Hill has a great idea, but if that's tile, it may be hard to screw through...

Answer (score 5):

Given that the finished appearance is entirely unimportant, a simple board spanning beneath the hole is an easy thing to install. It's the same idea as is sometimes used for repairing drywall.

Cut a piece of plywood, dimensional lumber, or something similar into a rectangle. Insert it through the hole, then drive screws down through the floor to draw the wood up to the bottom side of the floor. Finish up by placing a scrap of flooring, wood, etc into the hole to bring it up to the level of the surrounding floor.

It'll look something like the photo below. (photo from [drywall101.com](https://drywall101.com/en/articles/taping/strip-backed-drywall-patch); see there for additional description)

[image: drywall strap repair]

Comment: +1, but... It may depend on what the floor material is made of. Drywall is easy to drive a screw through to hold the board. If that's some sort of tile in the OP's floor, getting screws neatly through it might be more difficult.

Comment: It looks like the Euro equivalent of OSB to me. Typical subfloor. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest, safest solution would be to place a piece of sheet metal down (say 4" x 4").  You new range cooker should have adjustable legs to allow for the thickness.  If not, put a piece of sheet metal under each leg.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the ideas. In the end, I went to the timber yard, got a 10mm thick piece of board, had it cut to size, and just set it on top of the hole. I'm pretty confident that will work.

Comment: Sheetmetal will certainly deform, and it would need to be much larger for proper attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not know what the hole was for, I would leave it.

Assuming you will cover the floor with some tiles or something, find a proper size floor vent cover and just screw it on.

The vent could be at same hight as tiles, so an even surface.

If you ever find out what the hole was for, it is still there.

Comment: Given that the kitchen cabinet right next to the stove opening has an adjustable foot sitting on this same floor surface, it seems likely that this is the final, finished floor covering and that additional tile on top is not likely.

Comment: @FreeMan, tile floors are often installed around cabinetry in my region. It's somewhat rare for them to go under, as tile is expensive.